# Change name of point labels in

Tags: r, ggplot2, point, label, geom-text

I know how to add point labels when using ggplot2 using geom_text()

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, label=rownames(mtcars)))
p + geom_text()
```

[image]

But what if I want to change "Fiat X1-9" to "WORST CAR EVER" without changing the entries in the original dataframe? Is there a way to rename the point in the plot within geom_text()?

Thanks much.

Comment: The `label` argument can take in new names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the aesthetic or use it in the initial expression:

```
nms <- rownames(mtcars)
p + geom_text(aes(label = replace(nms, nms == "Fiat X1-9", "Worst Car Ever")))
```

**Edit**

If you do not want to create a new object you can use this. But as a point of advice, don't become too attached to one-liners. They are fun, but sometimes creating an object is the best for readability, debugging, and accuracy.

```
p + geom_text(aes(label = replace(rownames(mtcars), rownames(mtcars) == "Fiat X1-9", "Worst Car Ever")))
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a way to do it without creating any additional items (nms), but that works.  Much appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to create the extra object. It's only for looks.